# CSC version at computer

Tags: c#, version

I making fast changes in my code via Visual Studio Code. As you know it doesn't have build-in compiler so I using CSC via CMD.

It's working good only for ( code <= C# 4.6 & code <= .NET 4.5 ) because that version of CSC I have.

And there is problem because I writing in new C# 6.0 and .NET 4.6 and can't compile via CSC. 
I have installed VS 2015 with .NET 4.6 and compilie via VS 2015 working good.

I can't find CSC in version witch support CSC in version .NET 4.6 in my computer. I have .NET 4.6 in Windows Registry(regedit).

Comment: I'll randomly guess you are using the wrong csc.exe, there are lots of them.  You can see the one VS2015 uses when you change the build verbosity to Normal.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.  It runs C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, but that's only there when you have VS2015 installed. It's a shame the compiler is no longer a part of .NET Framework itself...

Comment: Hmya, not everybody likes open source I suppose: "what, I have to *compile* it?"  Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csc.exe` compiler used by Visual Studio 2015 is located at `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc2.exe`

Comment: csc.exe in this folder v. 4.6.81.0 and it is .NET 4.5

Comment: @Nerf, Sorry, checked again, its at `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc2.exe`

Comment: Hard to guess where that came from.  I suspect most users, like me, can only find csc.exe back in that directory.  Watch out for VS2015 or Roslyn beta versions, I guess.

Comment: In my case same directory, but file name is back to csc.exe. Compiles C# 6.0 properly.

Answer (score 4):

CSC is no longer used for compilation of C# 6+. The new standard compiler is Roslyn now.

In fact, `csc` itself tells you this:

> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

You need to download Roslyn (either using the link above and compiling it for yourself using MSBuild, or via NuGet at http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/) and use it to compile your programs from now on.