# Can't write an expression-bodied function member

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

**NOTE:** This appears to be a problem with the compiler that's used with SSDT projects, it's apparently fixed in the 2017 RC. My problem is similar to one described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011682/usage-of-wrong-compiler-during-sql-server-database-project-building)

I've got some code which refuses to let me write it as an expression-bodied function member. In short, I want to do this:

```
void foo() => bar();
```

But the IDE throws a tantrum and demands I write it like this:

```
void foo() { bar(); }
```

I mean sure, it's two extra characters but I'm not sure why it's complaining, the errors don't make sense either. It gives me the following 3 errors:

- CS0000: ; expected
- CS0000: Method must have a return type.
- CS0000: Identifier expected.

The full code looks like this.

```
public static void foo() => bar("some param"); // Errors on this line.
static void bar(string myParam) { //20 lines of code }
```

I've tested this in the C# interactive window and everything compiles and runs correctly. I can't find any unprintable characters in the code.

This is using VS 2015 community with the target framework being 4.6.1

Full code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class Triggers
{

    private const string ConnectionString = "context connection = true";

    private const string ReadInsertedTable = @"
    SELECT ID,
           (
               SELECT *
               FROM inserted AS b
               WHERE a.ID = b.ID
               FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS XSINIL
           )
    FROM inserted AS a
";
    [SqlTrigger(Name = "Person_Insert", Target = "Person", Event = "FOR INSERT")]
    public static void Person_Insert() => AuditInsert(TableName); //  All errors here.

    private const string TableName = "Person";

    private static void AuditInsert(string tableName)
    {

        using (var readConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var writeConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var readCommand = new SqlCommand(ReadInsertedTable, readConnection))
            {
                readConnection.Open();
                using (var reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    SqlContext.Pipe.Send((reader));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:** Code compiles using the msbuild utility but still fails in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have copied your code to  my vs and it compiled without errors

Comment: Any idea where to even start looking to try and fix this? Because CS0000 doesn't even seem to be a normal code. I'll add an image from my IDE.

Comment: what version of VS are you using? note that expression bodied members is feature of **C#6** so it does not work on old IDEs

Comment: VS2015 Community w/ Update 3.

Comment: It's important that you mention in which enviroment you're working. In a Visual Studio 2015/2017 you can add the new compiler features to the project via NUGET package manager -> Manage Packages for Solution. Open it and browse for `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. Then add it to the project and click INSTALL. Do the same for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`. Close NUGET and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will have something to do with Roslyn. Try to run this:

Non-roslyn:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJm1Fj

Roslyn:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/aMUsj0

I suspect there's something wrong either with your project file or your Visual Studio installation because VS2015 should use Roslyn-based compiler by default.

I'd try:

- creating a new project with the code from the fiddle above
- if it compiles then compare the differences in the *.csproj files, mainly the ToolsVersion `<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">` and targets `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`
- you should also look in the Output->Build window in VS and check out the executable being launched, in my case: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference ...  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin`
- if it doesn't compile, I'd suggest reinstalling .NET and VS

Comment: Looks like it's using an old compiler. The csc.exe I'm getting is under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe.

Any idea how to change it?

Comment: Have you tried to create the vanilla project as I suggested? I think there will be some differences in the project file, presumably in the targets section. Or maybe there is a specific language version set in the project file (Project properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language Version).

Comment: Yeah, I've just done that. It's to do with the project type. Apparently SQL Server Database Projects' (SSDT) don't use Roslyn.

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. Either try to merge it with the vanilla c# project template or just use a clean c# project. I don't know what's so specific about SSDT project but if you really need to use it, try extracting the aforementioned logic to a "pure c#" project.

Comment: I'll look into it later. I don't mind compiling and deploying this from the command line. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: ;) Glad to help

Comment: @Jake What do you see when you do as in rocky's first comment, that is __Project properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language Version__? Does the dropdown have only versions up to C# 5.0 for your project type?

Comment: I don't have Advanced under Build with an SSDT project.

Comment: @Jake I can reproduce what you see! If I create a new project, and choose "SQL Server Database Project", it creates a `.sqlproj` file, not a `.csproj` file. If in that SSDT project I add a new item and choose "SQL CLR C#" "Class", and in the resulting C# file use any C# 6.0 feature (also tried with an auto-property with initializer, `int P { get; set; } = 42;`), __I get strange errors__ when I try to "Build Solution (F6)".

Comment: That's pretty much what I did except I did a SQL CLR C# Trigger instead of a class.

Comment: I've put a link to that question at the top of my question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer turned out to be largely irrelevant.

As the asker figured out himself, with help from user rocky, the issue is that an **SQL Server Database Project** (`.sqlproj`) (unlike other projects of type `.csproj`) is not built with the new C# 6.0 compiler, at least not in Visual Studio 2015. The thread linked by the asker, [Usage of wrong compiler during SQL Server Database Project building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011682/), has some details.

---

Old answer:

**In your image**, the constant declaration:

```
private const string TableName = "Person";
```

is missing. However, you have not removed the `tableName` parameter from the `AuditInsert` method.

Comment: The code is fine, this appears to be a problem with the compiler used for SSDT projects. Apparently it's fixed in the 2017 RC, but I won't be installing that anytime soon. :-)

Comment: @Jake How can `AuditInsert(TableName)` be fine when there is no `TableName` defined anywhere? I am looking at your image.

Comment: The image was just to show that the errors appeared since Maksim said it compiled fine for him. We've already established it's a compiler issue, not a code one. I'm updating my main question accordingly with a link to a related question.