# In VS2015 a SQL Server project template incl. SQLCLR with C#6.0 does not compile

Tags: sql-server, templates, visual-studio-2015, sqlclr, c#-6.0

the VS2015 "SQL Server Database Project" template does not support SQLCLR functions with C#6.0 (.Net4.6) to be compiled.
The error message is

> "CSC: Error: CS1617: Invalid option '6' for /langversion; must be
>   ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default".

I have searched and found a lot for web projects like, e.g.
[Error Invalid option '6' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868803/error-invalid-option-6-for-langversion-must-be-iso-1-iso-2-3-4-5-or-defa)

Here you shall change the compiler in the `web.config`, like

> type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

But me, I do not have an app, nor a `web.config` in my database project. So what can I do to set the compiler for this project?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Finally I found this page https://www.codesd.com/item/using-an-incorrect-compiler-when-building-the-sql-server-database-project.html and it describes exactly what I got as my personal conclusion.

Comment: It works with msbuild (\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin) on command line but me I've reverted the changes back to C#5.0. Until I can move to VS2017, where the SQL project file uses an actual compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This seems very similar to, and maybe a duplicate of, the following question, also here on S.O.:

[Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452029/577765)

The issue is the C# compiler being used. If you go to a Developer Command Prompt and run **CSC.exe**, you should see a banner stating that the compiler only supports up to C# 5. And it provides a URL where to get a newer compiler from.

If the compiler does need to be specified in the project, then it would likely need to be manually added to the **.sqlproj** file, though there does not appear to be an existing element there already to set this value.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. So with just updating VS2015 and .Net SDK versions I cannot get to a running version because there is a compiler given ("Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.2558.0 for C# 5") with .Net 4.7.1 SDK (the actual one right now) that does still not support C#6.0. I really did not expect that.