# TFSBuild.proj keeps using the wrong csc.exe to build C#6.0 project

Tags: tfsbuild, roslyn

I have a TFSBuild.proj which keeps using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 csc.exe to build C#6.0 project. W.r.t [CSC version at computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698319/csc-version-at-computer/34713752#34713752), I have nugget install Roslyn but have no idea how to proceed further. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade msbuild to C# 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007871/how-to-upgrade-msbuild-to-c-sharp-6)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is installing VS2015 or [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) on the build server.

Then just need to set the build templates to point to MS Build version 14.0. For the details, check:[BuildActivity ignores ToolsVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion)

Comment: That works. I installed the build tool 2015 but I was not aware of setting the ToolPath in the workflow template .xaml file which fixes the issue. Anyway I still think this is a problem with the visual studio 2015 installation flaw that the csc.exe from the platform installed path does not work.